# How to use an observable without subcribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular 8 application and I am using a API call like this:

```
getDossierEntry(patientUUID: string,   type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/` + entryType);
}
```

And I have a parent component like this:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceComponent implements OnInit {

  correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;

  @Input() allCorrespondence: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input() correspondenceEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input() attachmentEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;

  message = '';
  emptyMessageCorrespondentie = 'Geen correspondentie.';
  errorMessageConnection = 'Er ging iets mis met de connectie. Probeer over enkele minuten nogmaals.';

  correspondenceLoaded = false;

  showingSingle = false;

  single: DossierEntry;

  constructor(
    private documentCorrespondeceService: DocumentCorrespondenceService,

    private authService: AuthService  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

    this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, () => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
    });
  }


   handleCorrespondenceLoad(result: any) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie;
      return;
    }
    this.allCorrespondence = result;
    this.attachmentEntries = [];
    this.correspondenceEntries = [];

    const groups = _.groupBy(result, 'type');
    this.correspondenceEntries = groups.correspondence;
    this.attachmentEntries = groups.attachments;
  }
}
```

And the html template looks like this:

```
<app-vital10-page [noTopBar]="true">
  <h2 class="dossier-page-header">Correspondentie</h2>

  <p class="data-entry" *ngIf="!allCorrespondence">{{ message }}</p>
  <app-is-loading *ngIf="!correspondenceLoaded" message="Correspondentie wordt geladen"></app-is-loading> 

  <app-dossier-correspondence-list [correspondenceEntries] = "correspondenceEntries$ | async" ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>
  <app-dossier-correspondence-item
    [item]="single"
    (goBack)="goBack($event)"
    *ngIf="showingSingle">
  </app-dossier-correspondence-item>
</app-vital10-page>
```

Then I have an child component like this:

```
export class DossierCorrespondenceListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  correspondenceEntries: DossierEntry[];

  @Input() showingSingle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!showingSingle  && correspondenceEntries && correspondenceEntries.length > 0;">
  <div class="main-row main-row-dossier">
    <section class="data-entry">
      <h3 class="dossier-header">Algemeen</h3>
      <table class="dossier-table" *ngIf="correspondenceEntries  else loadingCorrespondenceEntires ">
        <thead class="dossier-tableheader">
          <tr>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-one-fifth">Datum</th>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-four-fifths">Onderwerp</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dossier-tablebody">
          <tr class="dossier-correspondencerow" *ngFor="let entry of correspondenceEntries; let i = index" (click)="gotoItem(i, entry.type)">
            <td>{{ entry.date | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loadingCorrespondenceEntires>
  <div>..Loading </div>
</ng-template>
```

But now the data of the child component is not visible in the Parent component. But The correct data is loaded. Because If I do a console.log on this :

```
 this.correspondenceEntries = groups.correspondence;
    this.attachmentEntries = groups.attachments;
```

I see the correct arrays.But not in the view(htm file)

The problem is with this:

```
correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;
```

So my question is , how to pass the observable with this:

```
 this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

    this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, () => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
    });
  }
```

So that you dont have to use the subscribe method:

```
.subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, () => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
```

And that you will see the data in the view

Thank you.

So I want to do this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

 this.correspondenceEntries$ =   this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, () => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
    });
  }
```

But of course that doesn't work. But I don't know how to do it others?

So this is the output:

```
dossier-corresponden…ist.component.ts:21 
{correspondenceEntries: SimpleChange}
correspondenceEntries: SimpleChange
currentValue: null
firstChange: true
previousValue: undefined
```

oke, if  I do this:

```
<app-vital10-page [noTopBar]="true">
  <h2 class="dossier-page-header">Correspondentie</h2>

  <p class="data-entry" *ngIf="!allCorrespondence">{{ message }}</p>


<ng-container *ngIf="(correspondenceEntries$ | async) as correspondenceEntries">

  <app-dossier-correspondence-list [correspondenceEntries]="correspondenceEntries" ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>

</ng-container>


  <app-dossier-correspondence-item
    [item]="single"
    (goBack)="goBack($event)"
    *ngIf="showingSingle">
  </app-dossier-correspondence-item>
</app-vital10-page>
```

then still no output in view. But I get this in console:

```
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

But I see this:

```
currentValue: null
```

But if I do this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.correspondenceEntries$);

    this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

  this.correspondenceEntries$ =    this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence')
    });
  }
```

Then I see the items in the view.

But so I removed all this:

```
.subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, () => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
```

So is this correct?

No, this is not correct. Because now it will be one big list. ANd not two seperated lists(arrays)

Comment: why don't you get the data in child directly bcs it seems you not using that data in parent anywhere so instead of getting data in parent and pass it to child directly call tha service in child

Comment: Can you show how? Will be nice

Comment: oke, but the child is just a presentation view. I mean via the pattern smart-presentation components. that is not the correct way to do. What I have learned is that a presentation view will be not aware of the the data is comming from. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Check for the changes in the 'DossierCorrespondenceListComponent' to make sure you receive the data you expect. If yes, probably some template logic and/or style is blocking the data visibility.

Comment: Answering you question to use an Observable without subscribe manually is using the async pipe as you do to get the 'correspondenceEntries$' in the DossierCorrespondenceComponent's template. Using this approach angular subscribe and unsubscribe automatically.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean. The DossierCorrespondenceListComponent is now empty:export class DossierCorrespondenceListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  correspondenceEntries: DossierEntry[];

  @Input() showingSingle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

Comment: use the ngOnChanges(changes) { console.log(changes)}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199961/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-ricardo-ferreira).

Comment: I edit the post

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `as` keyword in the `*ngIf` directive that you can use as follows:

```
...
<ng-container *ngIf="(correspondenceEntries$ | async) as correspondenceEntries">
  ...
  <app-dossier-correspondence-list [correspondenceEntries]="correspondenceEntries" ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>
  ...
</ng-container>
...
```

The `as` keyword stores the value of what is before it (in this case the value emitted by the Observable and extracted by the async pipe) in the variable that follows it. Unfortunately [the `as` keyword is currently (i.e. Angular 8) only available within the `*ngIf` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280#issuecomment-532002162), so you have to use `*ngIf` even if you don't need the conditional template rendering aspect of it.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yt9gnw)

Comment: I tried your recommondation. But I dont see anyting in the view. It is very strange. Because the data is loaded. I see it in the console. But not in the view.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies within your application. I have added a link in my answer to a StackBlitz example that can hopefully help you track down your issue.

Comment: I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="correspondenceEntries">
    <app-dossier-correspondence-list [correspondenceEntries]="correspondenceEntries"> </app-dossier-correspondence-list>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="attachmentEntries">
    <app-dossier-correspondence-attachments
      [attachmentEntries]="attachmentEntries"
    ></app-dossier-correspondence-attachments>
  </ng-container>
```

So thank you all for you effort